# Intellij Tree with custom files in plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing intellij plugin and I have tree structure with files and directories (not related to current project nor file systems). Is is just some virtual tree structure provided by rest service. I want to display it in ToolWindow with all common staff like colors, file type icons etc.

Is my usecase already supported by intellij? 
Which classs support this?

The closes one related to my case I found trees from `vcs` package but it is commit / change related.

Comment: I was not precise, it is about plugin development, I edited question.

Comment: Yes, you can build such a tree in your plugin.

Comment: @yole thanks but is not the answer that i'm looking for:)

Comment: Well, that was the question you asked. What part exactly is presenting difficulties to you? Showing a tree? Displaying file icons? "Colors" (whatever you mean by that; colors are normally used to represent version control statuses, and it doesn't look like your files are managed by a version control system)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is formally supported by JetBrains, but you could create a "fake" project in Intellij IDEA as long as the files and directories you want to appear in the tools (Project) window have a single parent directory.

I had a folder named "docs2" which contained some random notes and documentation files of various types such as txt, pdf, zip, html, js and bak. I opened that directory as a project in Intellij IDEA's Project window as follows:

- Create an new project: **File -> New -> Project... -> Static Web -> Static Web**, then click the **Next** button:

[image: fakeProject1]

- On the next screen populate the **Project location** field by navigating to the folder containing the files you want to open in Itellij IDEA, and give the project a suitable name. Then click **Finish**.

[image: fakeProject2]

- After that Intellij IDEA will treat the directory as though it was a static web project.

[image: fakeProject3]

Notes:

- Intellij IDEA won't necessarily be able to handle all of the project files created in this manner. For example, when I opened a pdf file it was opened in another application, and when I tried to open a zip file nothing happened. But other known file types such as *.txt, *.html and *.js can be opened and edited as though they were files in a "real" project.
- When you open the directory as a project Intellij IDEA will create some files in that directory: a ***.iml** project file and a **.idea** folder containing configuration files, so you will need write access to the folder that you open as a project.
- I also tried opening the directory as an **Empty Project** in Intellij IDEA, but that only worked partially; files under the parent directory were shown, but for some reason it would not show any sub-directories in the project.

Comment: unfortunately it is not my use case. I'm looking for display this kind of tree in my plugin in ToolWindow, not in project view

Comment: @Martinus_Ah, OK. I had not realized that this was for your own plugin, and I had misread your post as relating to **View -> Tools Windows -> ...**.